# Eclipse indigo giving error validating xsd file

Tags: xml, eclipse, wsdl, xsd

This is probably a basic error for anyone with working knowledge of xml schemas and it probably is just a matter of a small config change in Eclipse Indigo, but it's exhausted my google search powers and all experiments failed to resolve it.

It's an xsd file in an existing project that functions happily. I am setting up the project to be a maven / dynamic web project in Eclipse and after turning on Eclipse's project facet for dynamic web project 2.4, Eclipse insists that I have problems with the file.

Here's the xsd start (with error logged on the pointer to `www.w3.org/2001/xmlschema`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<definitions 
    name="ThreeDSecureService" 
    targetNamespace="http://magpie.webservices.valueobject.domain.acme.com/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://magpie.webservices.valueobject.domain.acme.com/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <types>
```

and here are the errors:

> s4s-elt-invalid: Element 'definitions' is not a valid element in a
>   schema document.  magpie.xsd  /Model/src/main/resources   line 8  XML
>   Schema Problem
>
> s4s-elt-schema-ns: The namespace of element 'definitions' must be from
>   the schema namespace,
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'.   magpie.xsd  /Model/src/main/resources   line
>   8 XML Schema Problem
>
> schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document
>   'file:///home/adahar/projects/Model/src/main/resources/magpie.xsd',
>   because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be
>   read; 3) the root element of the document is not
>   . magpie.xsd  /Model/src/main/resources   line 8  XML Schema
>   Problem

Thanks for any help/advice.

Comment: Please read the answer before down-voting the question and docking my reputation, especially if you aren't going to leave comments to justify your actions. The error was caused by thoughtlessness and caused me enough hassle. The last thing I want is people anonymously hassling me for the way I tried to find a solution. I figured it would be useful for others to see what had happened. If you don't think so, then say so, and I'll delete the whole question, but how should I know if you don't leave any comment?

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the file was garbage. It was a .wsdl file with the wrong file extension and it shouldn't have been there anyway. So Eclipse's error was justified and I've learnt something about webservices, and XSD too. I will be more wary of files from our SCM which were checked in by the committer who did that.

Answer (score 0):

The root element of XSD must be `xsd:schema` (not `definitions`). Look at some XSD examples to see how to start. You need the `xsd:` prefix because the XML namespace for the XSD elements is set to `xsd` by this: `xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`

Comment: I tried that! I had to move the properties around and made it into this:

Comment: @Adam Having the xsd:schema as root is a must.

Comment: Sorry technical problems with the website! I wanted to post the version I made with root xsd:schema and the error that then appears...(coming up)

Comment: <xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="http://magpie.webservices.valueobject.domain.acme.com/"
    xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" 
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
    xmlns:tns="http://magpie.webservices.valueobject.domain.acme.com/" 
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<definitions name="ThreeDSecureService" >

Comment: OK @keyser5053 that xsd produces this error from Eclipse: 
s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of 'schema' is invalid.  Element 'definitions' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often. It looks like there's a semi-colon in there at the end of line 3 - but there's not really. Also the original version of the schema has obviously been working for a long time before I decided to turn the project into an eclipse dynamic web project, and also (and I'm not saying you're wrong here) this is the same style as the schema given at [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_wsdl)

Comment: @Adam Sounds like a formatting problem. Maybe [this](http://bytes.com/topic/xml/answers/895615-issues-writing-xsd-file) will help.

Comment: @keyser5053 thanks but I don't see the relevance. Read the whole doc and yes, the example problem there has a similar issue with the first node 'element' but that is valid for the namespace - my first node 'definitions' cannot be prefixed with xsd: becauce it gives the error 'the content of schema is invalid'.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256129.aspx is a pretty simple example. Why don't you start with that and modify it to meet your needs. I don't know where you are finding the `definitions` element, but it's not used at all in XSD.

Comment: The fact that I'm not finding the definitions element is actually the problem - see that link I posted earlier http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_wsdl - it is pretty much the same as what I am trying to do. I guess it was stupid to try prefixing 'definitions' with xsd: but I was just trying to show the previous posters what happens when I follow their suggestions. I think the issue is either an Eclipse config thing, or a matter of a quick tweak to the xsd.

Comment: The link you refer to is WSDL, not XSD. WSDL does contain a schema element and inside of the schema element it is XSD, but WSDL has a lot of other stuff. The Eclipse stuff deals only with XSD and is completely rock solid (I use it extensively).

Comment: Correct - but I'm not saying Eclipse is bust, I'm asking how I need to configure it to tell it to treat this file as WSDL and not XSD. If possible. Meanwhile I'm going to check to see why it's called magpie.xsd and magpie.wsdl and whether in fact it will make any difference if I just rename the file extension.

Comment: By the way sorry if you xml schema guys are rolling your eyes now. Never worked with web services or wsdl before.

Comment: @Adam I'm not :p I really can't understand the problem (which could mean there's a problem with eclipse as you mentioned)

Comment: To recap so far it looks like this: I have an .xsd file which appears to be a WSDL file from its content and I don't know why it's there in the source code repository. If I change the extension to .wsdl, then Eclipse is happy. But I don't know why it's not .wsdl, so I trying to track down the person who committed it to ask why (if they know why!). Everything seems to work with the new file extension - I thought I'd have to change something else in the application config to take care of that but it appears to work regardless. If anyone recognises wtf is going on, feel free to shout.